# C++ choosing certain set on characters from any string

Tags: c++

Quick question.

I am currently trying to make a very simple hangman game, but I am having trouble with checking if a user's guess is equal to any of the characters in a randomly chosen word. This is a bit of my current code:

```
    char wrongchoice;
    int tries = 0;
    string wordList[10] = {"Family", "School", "Terraria", "Algebra", 
    "Computer", "House", "Intelligent", "Advanced", "Science", "Despacito"};

    srand(time(0));
    int wordNum = rand() % 10;
    string chosenWord = wordList[wordNum];

    string Wholewordanswer = chosenWord;

    char answer;
```

I just don't know how to check: When the user inputs an alphabetical character, a while loop will check between index 0 and the longest word's final index if the character matches up. If anyone could tell or leave an example of this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Edit 1:

I should have said that I am quite new to using C++. I can only do a handful of the basics. I hope you guys understand.

Comment: Use `string::find` to see if a character or substring is in a string. You can read about it here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: Loop over each character in the string, comparing it to the character you read from the user. If equal then mark it as "ok" (perhaps through a separate array or vector or string?). If not found the loop will end and you can check for that condition to do whatever's needed then.

Answer (score 0):

Why iterate through the string, you can use `find()` :

```
bool hasChar(char c,string s) {
    return s.find(c) == string::npos ? false : true;
}
```

And then just read a char, and send it to this method with the string .

Comment: why iterate through the string? Because that required to find a character in a string (and thats what `string::find` does)

Comment: yeah, I just dont like the "what you dont see is not there" approach of thinking :P